# Remote access to Huawei E3372 WebInterface on headless RaspberryPi

Tags: forwarding, huawei-mobile-services, lte

I'm trying to (remotely) connect to the E3372's (Huawei LTE stick) WebInterface...

The E3372 is recognised by my RaspberryPi as "12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd." - so it seems to be in HiLink-mode. Good.

using

```
> ifconfig
```

I see that the stick uses eth1 / 192.126.8.100
and the WebInterface's web-server is supposed to run on 192.168.8.1...

To verify this, on the Pi (from PC using ssh to eth0 with a DHCP-assigned IP-address of 192.168.10.123) I can e.g. query (read) the starting-page of the E3372's WebInterface using:

```
> curl 192.168.8.1/html/home.html
```

...so obviously the web-server is up-and-running!

Now I try to forward connections on eth0's port=80 (192.168.10.123:80) to 192.168.8.1:80, so I can then access the WebInterface from an external PC connected to the Pi's eth0; so I:

1) enable ip4-port-forwarding:

```
> sudo nano /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

--> and change the '0' to '1'

2) use iptables to set the appropriate forwarding:

```
> sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.8.1:80
> sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.8.1 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Now using a browser on the PC with the URL "http://192.168.10.123" yields (after some seconds): "This site can’t be reached"...

please help! what's wrong here???

Thanks for helping!

Comment: 192.168.10.123 is a local IP. You cannot access that through your PC remotely (unless you are on the same LAN, which is obviously not the case as the Huawei E3372 does not serve the address of your PC)